# Абстрактные классы

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, список, std-list

У меня есть абстрактный класс GeometryObjects и три класса наследника Point (точка), Line (2 точки), Polyline (список точек).  Я создал список геометрических объектов:

```
list<GeometryObjects*> *a = new list<GeometryObjects*>;
```

А затем добавил в него определённым образом объекты типа Point, Line, Polyline. Сейчас мне необходимо получить доступ к некоторым полям объектов дочерних классов.

```
list<GeometryObjects*> *ls;
GeometryObjects* myGObj;
list<GeometryObjects*>::iterator it = ls->begin();
advance(it, index);
myGObj = *it;
```

Но у myGObj я могу вызывать только методы, описанные в абстрактном классе. Может, возможно как-то преобразовать GeometryObjects* в Point/Line/Polyline?

Comment: Напишите C++ по-английски.

Answer (score 3):

Смысл абстрактного класса Вашего типа - единообразная работа с разными объектами. Поэтому то, что Вы хотите - очевидно плохой паттерн.
Теоретически, Вы можете добавить абстрактному классу метод "GetType", с, соответственно, разными реализациями у наследников, и создать класс GeometryControl с методом Invoke(GeometryObjects* go, GeometryType& type), который будет внутри себя вызывать dynamic_cast и преобразовывать указатель на родителя к указателю на ребенка. Но это плохой стиль.

В Вашем случае я бы отказался вообще от иерархии, сделайте класс GeometryObject не абстрактным, способным содержать в себе набор точек. И два класса: "Point" - точка и "Painter" - рисователь.

И храните список GeometryObject, имея прямой доступ до "внутренностей".

Одной реализации Painter хватит, чтобы рисовать и точку, и линию, и фигуру из линий. А вот для всяких эллипсов и прочая - придется делать другие реализации Painter-а (тут-то наследование и может пригодиться), которые и передавать в GeometryObject.
Причем, я бы отказался от Painter, как базового абстракного для рисователей в пользу `template<typename T> class Painter;` с соответствующими реализациями метода Paint() для разного типа фигур (которые можно задавать пустыми типами `class Square {}; class Ellipse {}; class Polyline {};`

Это же позволит при конструировании класса Painter передавать ему радиус и другие settings, если надо.

Comment: Возможно, я неправильно понял ваш ответ, но то, что я хотел, делается с помощью dynamic_cast.

Comment: @virty90: Вы поняли неправильно. Вам _не должно_ хотеться сделать `dynamic_cast`, это указывает, что у вас не всё хорошо с архитектурой.

Ваш код либо не должен знать, какие именно конкретные типы лежат в списке, и не отнаследовал ли кто-нибудь ещё один класс от вашего класса (и тогда вызывать методы за пределами списка общих не нужно), либо вам не нужна виртуализация вовсе, и вам следует хранить отдельный списки объектов конкретного типа.

Comment: @virty90, вариант с dynamic_cast я для этого и указал. Но есть большое "НО", которое объяснил VladD.

Comment: только сейчас заметил в вашем ответе dynamic cast...